# D3 JS: How to add transition to refresh a plot when the dataset x-scale changes?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js, svg

Looking at this [Histogram chart using d3 example](http://bl.ocks.org/nnattawat/8916402) I plugged in my data but it had some strange side effects e.g. after refreshing to a new dataset, some information from the previous dataset i.e. x-axis scale was retained. I tried deleting and appending a new x-axis etc but nothing worked.

This happened due to the fact that my datasets had completely different x-axis ranges and scales. The only way I found to make it work was to select the whole `svg` element, remove it and re-append everything anew. However, this doesn't make a pleasant transition for the user so I was wondering how can this be improved to make it refreshable using transitions as in the original example even when having datasets with different x-scales and ranges.

This was my last approach which is a bit harsh to the eye:

```
// delete old
d3.select("#" + divId).select("svg").remove();

// then recreate all new
```

And this was my refresh attempt (integrated with AngularJS). Note how it has some common initialization and then if the SVG doesn't exist appends everything new otherwise tries to update it. I went bit by bit but can't see why the refresh doesn't remove all the previous dataset information of the x-axis scale:

```
var divId = $scope.histogramData.divId;
var color = $scope.histogramData.color;
var values = $scope.histogramData.data[$scope.histogramData.selected];
var svg = $scope.histogramData.svg;

// plot common initialization
var margin = {top: 40, right: 20, bottom: 20, left: 20},
    width = 450 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 370 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var max = d3.max(values);
var min = d3.min(values);
var x = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([min, max])
    .range([0, width]);

// generate a histogram using twenty uniformly-spaced bins.
var data = d3.layout.histogram()
    .bins(x.ticks(10))
    (values);

var yMax = d3.max(data, function(d){ return d.length });
var yMin = d3.min(data, function(d){ return d.length });
var colorScale = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([yMin, yMax])
    .range([d3.rgb(color).brighter(), d3.rgb(color).darker()]);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, yMax])
    .range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom");

// ===================================================================
// If the SVG doesn't exist then adds everything new
// ===================================================================
if (svg === undefined) {
    var svg = d3.select("#" + divId)
        .append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
    $scope.histogramData.svg = svg;

    var bar = svg.selectAll(".bar")
        .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append("g")
        .attr("class", "bar")
        .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + x(d.x) + "," + y(d.y) + ")"; });

    bar.append("rect")
        .attr("x", 1)
        .attr("width", (x(data[0].dx) - x(0)) - 1)
        .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.y); })
        .attr("fill", function(d) { return colorScale(d.y) });

    bar.append("text")
        .attr("dy", ".75em")
        .attr("y", -12)
        .attr("x", (x(data[0].dx) - x(0)) / 2)
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
        .text(function(d) { return formatCount(d.y); });

    var gTitle = svg.append("text")
        .attr("x", 0)
        .attr("y", 0 - (margin.top / 2))
        .attr("text-anchor", "left")
        .classed("label", true)
        .text($scope.histogramData.spec[selected]);
    $scope.histogramData.gTitle = gTitle;

    var gAxis = svg.append("g")
     .attr("class", "x axis")
     .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
     .call(xAxis);
     $scope.histogramData.gAxis = gAxis;

} else {
    // ===================================================================
    // If the SVG does exist then tries refreshing
    // ===================================================================
    var bar = svg.selectAll(".bar").data(data);

    // remove object with data
    bar.exit().remove();

    bar.transition()
        .duration(1000)
        .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + x(d.x) + "," + y(d.y) + ")"; });

    bar.select("rect")
        .transition()
        .duration(1000)
        .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.y); })
        .attr("fill", function(d) { return colorScale(d.y) });

    bar.select("text")
        .transition()
        .duration(1000)
        .text(function(d) { return formatCount(d.y); });

    var gTitle = $scope.histogramData.gTitle;
    gTitle.transition()
          .duration(1000)
          .text($scope.histogramData.spec[selected]);

    var gAxis = $scope.histogramData.gAxis;
    gAxis.transition()
         .duration(1000)
         .call(xAxis);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest to keep this d3 code inside one angularJS directive and keep a watch on the json which you are using to plot that graph. As soon as values are changing the directive will be called again and the graph will be plotted. Hope it helps.